# Constructor call in inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have a very naïve question.
I have the following code in Python:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("constructor A")

class B(A):
    pass

ob = B()
```

It gives the following output:

```
constructor A
```

Similarly in the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'{self.name}')
          
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):   
        print('Class B constructor')   
  
ob1 = B() 
ob2 = B('abc')
```

Shouldn't the output be:

```
class B constructor
abc
```

In fact it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: B.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Isn't `def __init__(self,name)` of `class A` gets inherited in `class B` and can't we call it using `ob2 = B('abc')`?

Comment: The inherited `__init__()` methods are not called automatically like in `c++`

Comment: The constructor in B accepts not parameter (other than self), but you try to pass a string into it.

Comment: `A` `__init__`  won't be called without calling it explicitly in `B` `__init__`, `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @Guy then why are we not explicitly calling it in the first code?

Comment: Because you don't override the parent `__init__` in the first code.

Comment: @Guy Is the `__init__(self)` really overriding the `__init__(self, name)` when both have different number of arguments?

Comment: In python the number of arguments don't matter. Its the overriding which matters. The `__init__()` method is like any other method. When a method is defined in `B` which has the same name as a method in `A`, then the most derived one is called.

Comment: Python is not OO language like Java, it doesn't have the overloading concept. The interpreter looks at the function name, not the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Just to mention, `__init__` is not constructor, it's *initializer*. It initializes the newly created object returned from `__new__`.

No, it Python attributes(including methods) of the classes are resolved using `mro`(Method Resolution Order), Whenever Python finds that, it stops going further.

In this example, Python didn't find `fn` in C, so it checks B, then A, and now it finds it. (If it didn't find it in A, it checks `object` class which is the last class in every class's MRO. In that case it raises `AttributeError` because `object` doesn't have `fn` either)

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def fn():
        print("fn in A")

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

print(C.mro())
C.fn()
```

output:

```
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
fn in A
```

If for example `B` has defined `fn`, it stops there:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def fn():
        print("fn in A")

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def fn():
        print("fn in B")

class C(B):
    pass

print(C.mro())
C.fn()
```

output:

```
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
fn in B
```

Same thing happens to `__init__`.

If you want your code to work, you need to call the `A`'s initializer inside the `B`'s initializer. Note that the signature of the `B`'s `__init__` should compatible with the `A`'s `__init__`. By compatible I mean it should take at least the number of parameters that `A`'s `__init__` takes, because you're going to pass those parameters to `A.__init__`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Class A initializer")
        self.name = name
        print(f"{self.name}")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        print("Class B initializer")


ob2 = B("abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'{self.name}')


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            super(B, self).__init__(name=args[0])
        else:
            print('Class B constructor')


ob1 = B()
ob2 = B('abc')
```

`*args` can control how many objects you enter, in that situation we can enter 1 or 0 objects. 
if you enter 0 objects in your constructor, it will generate `('Class B constructor')`, but if you enter 1 object, with `super()` method you call the A class constructor and `name` is equals to object, that is entered in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `__init__()` in `A` to be called, you have to do it yourself:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'{self.name}')
          
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('Class B constructor')   
        super().__init__(name):
  
ob2 = B('abc')
```

Output

```
class B constructor
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override constructor inside class B. class B inheritances from class A. And class A constructor except name argument. You don't need add **init** method inside B class here. One of the advantage using OOP is to reduces repetition. You decided to which parameters parent class will have. If you don't use parent class attributes in child class then there is no logic to create parent class. In short, parent class store attributes and methods in common, and if you want, you can add more attributes and method to child classes.

Code snippet will be like this

```
class A:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
    print(f'{self.name}')
class B(A):
  def __init__(self,name):
    super().__init__(name, ...) # here you can add attributes that is specific to B class
    print('Class B constructor')   


ob2 = B('abc')
```

Answer (score -1):

it's because you `__init__` take only one argument `self` which is always passed you need to add name to the definition of B

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'{self.name}')
      
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):   
        print('Class B constructor')   

ob2 = B('abc')
```

Comment: This doesn't invoke `A.__init__` though…